# How to remove "Open in Finder" from a Stack on the Dock when viewed as a Grid?

Tags: dock

Is there a way I can remove "Open in Finder" from a Stack on the Dock when viewed as a Grid?

I'm referring to the icon the red arrow is pointing to in the example image below.

[image]

Comment: What version of macOS are you using?

Comment: I am using MacOS Sierra